# How long is a second in zero gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

General relatively predicts that gravity creates time dilation and a relatively slower passage of time for the observer experiencing larger acceleration. For an observer experiencing zero acceleration, including being far enough from any mass that the gravitational forces are approaching zero, how long is one of their seconds compared to a second on the surface of the Earth?

It seems like [Schwarzschild Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_coordinates) as a means for calculating [time dilation outside a non-rotating sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Outside_a_non-rotating_sphere) is the right approach, but I’m not a physicist, just an engineer who saw Intersellar last night and needs some expert help to wrap my mind around this.

Comment: Interestingly, you linked us to the gravitational time dilation page from wikipedia, which answers your question exactly. It even gives the length of one second on Earth relative to an observer far from it. Or rather, it says how many seconds less per year an observer on Earth experiences. As an engineer myself, I'd think surely you can isolate the equation for $t_f$ and plug 1s into $t_0$ and solve

Comment: This topic is discussed a bit in the book by Kip Thorne, "The Science of Interstellar".  I saw Interstellar yesterday and started reading the book last night although I have had the book for more than a week.  The book contains spoilers on the movie and it is best to read after seeing the movie.

Comment: @Jim. I was hoping the link was relevant, it certainly seemed so, but I'd rather have actual physicists confirm that assume the first wikipedia hit is being interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record, your opening statement:

> General relatively predicts that gravity creates time dilation and a relatively slower passage of time for the observer experiencing larger acceleration

is incorrect, or at least misleading. For example an observer moving in a circle at speed $v$ in flat spacetime is experiencing acceleration towards the centre of the circle (the centripetal force). However the time dilation is just dependant on the speed $v$ and is given by the usual equation for motion in a straight line:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$

Obviously the acceleration depends on the velocity so I suppose you could write the time dilation as a function of acceleration, but this would be misleading as it's the displacement in space (i.e. the velocity) that causes the time dilation.

Anyhow, the time measured on a clock carried by the astronaut in the gravitational field of a non-rotating sphere is given by the Schwarzschild metric:

$$ d\tau^2 = \left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)dt^2 - \frac{dr^2}{\left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)} - r^2 d\Omega^2 $$

If the atronaut is hovering at a fixed position then $dr = d\Omega = 0$ and the expression simplifies to:

$$ d\tau^2 = \left(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}\right)dt^2 $$

and the time dilation (relative to an observer far from the black hole) is therefore:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}} $$

But, this will not correctly describe the time dilation in Interstellar because that was around a rotating black hole. In fact for a static black hole there is a minimum distance $6GM/c^2r$ below which nothing can maintain a stable orbit, and even at this distance the time dilation is not as great as in Interstellar. To correctly describe the very high time dilation in the film you have to use the Kerr metric that describes a rotating black hole. You also need to take into account the time dilation from both the spacetime curvature and the orbital velocity of the astronaut.

The trouble is that while the Schwarzschild metric is simple enough that I can describe the calculation to you in a few lines this is not true of the Kerr metric.

Comment: I blame `Interstellar` for this question.

Comment: And that is why I asked the question. The business of rotating and non-rotating frames was not obvious (to me). It sounds like there is a combination of two effects that the Kerr metric accounts for and the simple Schwarzschild metric does not. It appears either way the difference between a second here on Earth and one in the idealized non-rotating, gravityless void is very small.

Comment: _"the time dilation is just dependant on the speed v"_ This sounds like your are talking about Special Relativity? In General Relativity time dilation is caused by gravity. In some ways acceleration is equivalent with gravity. Isn't that what OP is thinking about?

Answer (score 3):

Gravitational time dilation relates to the gravitational potential $\Phi$, not the gravitational field $g$, so comparing earth's $g$ with $g=0$ doesn't give the relevant information.

An example of a question that does have an answer would be how long is a second aboard a GPS satellite, compared to a second at the earth's surface? The answer is that gravitational time dilation makes the clock on the satellite run faster by a factor of $1+\Delta\Phi/c^2=1.00000000045$.